# Running multiple async calls to mongolab fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run multiple calls in a forEach loop to my free/sandbox mongolab db instance and get empty response while if I Run the same one after the other (waiting for a response then sending the second) works:

**here is my forEach:**

```
router.get('/api/dashboard', function(req, res){
  var users = cacheAgent.get('users');
  var stats = { balance: [] };
  users.asArray.forEach(function(user){
    getUserBalance(user.id, function(userBalance){
        stats.balance.push({ id: user.id, name: user.name, balance: userBalance.balance });
        if (stats.balance.length == users.asArray.length){
          res.json( {users: users, stats:stats} );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**And the actual function:**

```
var getUserBalance = function(userId, callbackFn){
  console.log('getting balance for user: ' + userId);
  Record.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: '$action'},
...
    ], function(err, result){
      //console.log({ balance: result[0], error: err });
      callbackFn({ balance: result[0].userTotal });
    });
}
```

If I run a single getUserBalance on a request and call that url one after the other I get no issue, for example:

```
router.get("/api/getbalance/:id",function(req,res){
  var userId = req.params.id;
  getUserBalance(req.params.id, function(result){res.json(result)});
});
```

not sure if its relevant but the query is a mongo aggregate function, and after it crushes not even a single call that worked before works, I have to re-launch application

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this by performing a $in operation in your aggregation query and then use $group later on in the aggregation pipeline to group by userId. This way you don't have to hit the database multiple times (once for each user) and you can avoid relying on what looks like slightly precarious logic to 'break' out of your foreach loop. Here is an example which you'll have to change to fit to your requirements.

EDIT: You can simply add res.json to your callback. Either that or you can get rid of your callback function altogether:

```
var getUsersBalance = function(userIds) {    
Record.aggregate([
  { userId: { $in: userIds } } // userIds is an array
  { $unwind: '$action'},
  ...
  { $group: { /* group by userId */ }  }
 ], function(err, result){
   res.json(results);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, That's a good idea, I'll change the flow.
I do still wonder what caused this issue as it may raised later on in a much more complex case that cannot be resolved like that :)
But it will solve this current issue, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! I think the reason you're having problems is because JavaScript is single threaded. You need to tell each iteration of your for loop that it has completed before proceeding. Check out this answer for a detailed explanation: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176957/looping-array-and-checking-mongodb-collection-in-loop-async